# Eclipse integration with pep8 on mac os x lion

Tags: python, pydev, pep8

I am trying to set pep8 correctly in Eclipse for PyDev projects, everything seems to be configured properly - it was already configured with PyDev, but I also followed some tutorials found on web to check if everything is allright and I think it is, but it still doesn't work.

I made on purpose some unused import and methods in camelcase notation, but still I don't get even one tiny warning.

Here is my configuration of Eclipse->Prefrences->PyDev->Editor->Code analysis :

```
1st tab Do code analysis + On any succesful parse are checked 
6th tab Pep8 warning is checked, redirect pep8 output to console is checked too
path to pep8 ==> /Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062818/pysrc/third_party/pep8/pep8.py
```

I tried to play with these settings, but didn't help so I left them at default.

I did restarted Eclipse few times, I am using mac os x 10.7.5

Answer (score 0):

The [`pep8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) tool does not check CamelCase methods or unused imports:

- For naming conventions, try the experimental `pep8-naming` plugin (on PyPI).
- For unused imports, this is covered by `pyflakes` (on PyPI).

And all these tools are wrapped into the [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) checker.

Comment: Well some time ago I was developing on ubuntu in eclipse with PyDev plugin and I pep8 did checked methods names and unused imports, I don't know why there is a diffrent effect now. But I will see plugins you have given above. thanks

Comment: Eclipse has several code analysis tools. Maybe you saw warnings from PyLint which reports unused imports.